# How to add Source Code Google Api in Eclipse?

Tags: android, google-maps

Tell me how to add Source Code Google Api in Eclipse?

In Android SDK Manager everything is installed.
In android.jar added JavaDoc and source code, but only shows Android classes.

For example, I want to see the contents of the class MapView?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must choose project version Google APIs 2.2 instead of Android 2.2.

[image]

And add this in AndroidManifext.xml:

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

And also permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- for internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> <!-- for GPS-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <!-- for GPS-->
```

As for the source code you can find it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/com/google/android/maps/MapView.java). But it a bit problematic to add source code of Google APIs to your project. You can use [andoid developers site](http://developer.android.com/index.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you, I know a project to do, I was only interested in Javadoc from Foofle API. Well, if this is not possible. thanks for share.